# How do I create a unique ID for each night-time period across consecutive dates?

Tags: r, time, time-series, uniqueidentifier

I have data collected continuously over consecutive days. Each  observation already contains the variables datetime (a POSIXct object) and par (a numeric object). I want to create a new variable called ID which will be a unique number associated with an individual night-time period. I will define night-time as all observations where par = 0. An example of what I would like my data to look like is given below for 3 consecutive days.

Note: my actual data is taken at 15-minute intervals, but I truncated this example for easier viewing.

```
              datetime    par    ID
1  2015-04-23 00:00:00    0.0     1
2  2015-04-23 08:00:00    0.0     1
3  2015-04-23 12:00:00  817.7     0
4  2015-04-23 19:00:00    0.0     2
5  2015-04-24 00:00:00    0.0     2
6  2015-04-24 08:00:00    0.0     2
7  2015-04-24 12:00:00  269.9     0
8  2015-04-24 19:00:00    0.0     3
9  2015-04-25 00:00:00    0.0     3
10 2015-04-25 08:00:00    0.0     3
11 2015-04-25 12:00:00 1701.8     0
12 2015-04-25 19:00:00    0.0     4
13 2015-04-25 23:00:00    0.0     4
```

I would like non-night (par !=0) observations have ID = 0. The first night-time period occurs on 4/23/2015, so I want it's ID = 1. I then want to add 1 to each following night-time period ID.

Any ideas? Despite much effort, I have not been able to achieve the above result. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `cumsum`:

```
df$ID2 <- 0
sel <- df$par == 0
df$ID2[sel] <- cumsum(!sel)[sel] + 1

#      par ID ID2
#1     0.0  1   1
#2     0.0  1   1
#3   817.7  0   0
#4     0.0  2   2
#5     0.0  2   2
#6     0.0  2   2
#7   269.9  0   0
#8     0.0  3   3
#9     0.0  3   3
#10    0.0  3   3
#11 1701.8  0   0
#12    0.0  4   4
#13    0.0  4   4
```

Comment: Super clever.  Would have to order the data if they weren't already ordered though.

Comment: @Barker - true, good point. `rle` etc would hit the same snags.

Comment: True, but I like yours better so that is the one I commented on.

Comment: @thelatemail - Applying the above code as-is seems very close to working! My first night-time period is correctly labelled with 1, but my following night-time period IDs jump to 59, then 118, 176, etc. The difference between these values (~59) are the number of rows separating each night-time period (for my original 15-minute interval data). I've tried ordering the data frame first as Barker noted, but I get the same issue.  Thoughts? I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @h20joe - you can probably convert them back to a factor - something like `as.numeric(factor(df$ID2))-1`

Comment: @thelatemail - That last line of code did the trick. Thanks! Here is everything together:                                                                           df$ID2 <- 0
sel <- df$par == 0
df$ID2[sel] <- cumsum(!sel)[sel] + 1                           as.numeric(factor(df$ID2))-1

Answer (score 2):

I would start by converting your `POSIXct` dates into `POSIXlt` dates because these have attributes which make determining things like days easier.

```
df[["datetime"]] <- as.POSIXlt(df[["datetime"]])
```

We can then use the fields `yday` and `hour` to get a numeric value where anything past noon in a 24 hour period a has the same value.  This will only work if all your times are in the same year.  If not, you will have to use the `year` attribute to adjust the days.

```
indicator <- df[["datetime"]][["yday"]] + (df[["datetime"]][["hour"]] > 12)
```

Using factor levels, we can then get the order numbers starting at 1.

```
df[["ID"]] <- as.numeric(as.factor(indicator))
```

Then we can set all `day` periods to `0`.

```
df[["ID"]][df[["par"]] != 0] <- 0
```

This can be done in two lines if so desired.

```
df[["ID"]] <- as.numeric(as.factor(df[["datetime"]][["yday"]] + 
                                (df[["datetime"]][["hour"]] > 12)))
df[["ID"]][df[["par"]] != 0] <- 0
```

This solution will work no matter what order your data are in.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways, both employing run-length-encoding

### data.table

This uses the fact that time periods are grouped by date, so we can use run-length-encoding to group the values on the same date. Then anything with a `par > 0` can be set to 0.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
## explicitly ordering the data.table
df[order(datetime), ID := rleid(as.Date(datetime))][ par > 0, ID := 0]
df
#               datetime    par ID
# 1:  2015-04-23 00:00:00    0.0  1
# 2:  2015-04-23 08:00:00    0.0  1
# 3:  2015-04-23 12:00:00  817.7  0
# 4:  2015-04-23 19:00:00    0.0  2
# 5:  2015-04-24 00:00:00    0.0  2
# 6:  2015-04-24 08:00:00    0.0  2
# 7:  2015-04-24 12:00:00  269.9  0
# 8:  2015-04-24 19:00:00    0.0  3
# 9:  2015-04-25 00:00:00    0.0  3
# 10: 2015-04-25 08:00:00    0.0  3
# 11: 2015-04-25 12:00:00 1701.8  0
# 12: 2015-04-25 19:00:00    0.0  4
# 13: 2015-04-25 23:00:00    0.0  4
```

(This is my preferred solution as it can handle any dates, correctly orders the data, and is efficient because, you know, data.table...)

---

### base

If the 'night time period' are always separated by a 'daytime' period, then you can also do it this way

```
## create an ID column set the 'daytime' periods to 0
df[ df$par != 0, "ID"] <- 0

## get the run-length-encoding of the ID column
r <- rle(is.na(df$ID))

## the length of the rle where the value is TRUE gives us teh number of NAs in each 'group', so we can replicate the rle value by that amount
rep(1:length(r$lengths[r$values]), r$length[r$values])
# [1] 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4

## so you can fill the rest of hte column with these values

df[ df$par == 0, "ID"] <- rep(1:length(r$lengths[r$values]), r$length[r$values])
df
#               datetime    par ID
# 1  2015-04-23 00:00:00    0.0  1
# 2  2015-04-23 08:00:00    0.0  1
# 3  2015-04-23 12:00:00  817.7  0
# 4  2015-04-23 19:00:00    0.0  2
# 5  2015-04-24 00:00:00    0.0  2
# 6  2015-04-24 08:00:00    0.0  2
# 7  2015-04-24 12:00:00  269.9  0
# 8  2015-04-24 19:00:00    0.0  3
# 9  2015-04-25 00:00:00    0.0  3
# 10 2015-04-25 08:00:00    0.0  3
# 11 2015-04-25 12:00:00 1701.8  0
# 12 2015-04-25 19:00:00    0.0  4
# 13 2015-04-25 23:00:00    0.0  4
```